# iOS compare button title to string

Tags: objective-c, string, ios

I'm just learning how to code so thanks for your patience on this simple question.

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender {  
    NSString *buttonName = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    if (buttonName == @"Button 1") {  
        do something 
    }
```

How do I compare the title of the button passed as sender to a string?

Much thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in objective-c you can't compare strings using "==", 
instead you should use the method `isEqualToString` from the NSString class to compare a string with another.

```
if ([buttonName isEqualToString: @"Button 1"]) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: i would also suggest you take a few minutes and have a look at NSString and its methods, there's a lot in there you will need at some point: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll be sure to check out that doc.

Answer (score 3):

Use -isEqualToString method:

```
if ([buttonName isEqualToString:@"Button 1"])
   ...
```

using `==` you compare ponters, not the actual string values they contain

Answer (score 1):

The better way to compare string is:

```
NSString *string1 = <your string>;
NSString *string2 = <your string>;

if ([string1 caseInsensitiveCompare:string2] == NSOrderedSame) {
    //strings are same
} else {
    //strings are not same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that with Xcode 8.3.1, it is necessary to do:

```
if([self.myButton isEqual: @"My text"]) {
//do this
}
```