# UILabel Text Compare with String

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS compare button title to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270260/ios-compare-button-title-to-string)

Can someone tell me how to compare UIlabel and a String @"abc".

lets say if(UIlabel??? == @"abc");

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS compare button title to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270260/ios-compare-button-title-to-string), [Check the text of a label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547699/), [Compare the text of two fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905751/), and [plenty more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+%22string%22+comparison).

Comment: Indeed...this question is one of the most frequently answered questions on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"abc"]
```

Comment: With an @ symbol in front of the quotes @"abc"

Comment: [myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"abc"]